# Why printf is not able to handle flags, field width and precisions properly?

Tags: c, printf, libc, conversion-specifier

I'm trying to discover all capabilities of printf and I have tried this :

```
printf("Test:%+*0d", 10, 20);
```

that prints

> Test:%+100d

I have use first the flag `+`, then the width `*` and the re-use the flag `0`.

Why it's make this output ? I purposely used `printf()` in a *bad* way but I wonder why it shows me the number 100?

Comment: "I purposely use printf in a bad way" and thus you get UB, anything may happen.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right, but I have to recode a function that reproduce the behaviour of printf

Comment: Do you have to implement the undefined behavior of printf, or just the defined behavior?  Hopefully just the defined behavior.  (If not, you've got an impossible task, because different implementations of printf implement undefined behavior differently; which will you mimic?) In this case, the problem (that I'm hoping you don't have to worry about) is that the `0` flag follows the width specifier `*`.

Comment: What is the _bad way_ you mentioned? Are you actually aware of the mistake?

Comment: `printf("Test:%+*0d", 10, 20);` --> `printf("Test:%+*.0d", 10, 20);`

Comment: It's likely not your duty to replicate the exact behavior of your implementation in the presence of ill-formed input. So simply forget about the precise behavior that you observe and focus on the results of well-formed input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, you're supplying *syntactical nonsense* to the compiler, so it is free to do whatever it wants. Related reading, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Compile your code with warnings enabled and it will tell you something like

> warning: unknown conversion type character ‘0’ in format [-Wformat=]
>        `printf("Test:%+*0d", 10, 20);`
>         `^`

To be correct, the statement should be either of

- `printf("Test:%+*.0d", 10, 20);  // note the '.'`

  where, the `0` is used as a ***precision***

  Related, quoting the `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, (*emphasis mine*)

  > An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the `d`, `i`,
  >   `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point
  >   character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, the maximum number of significant
  >   digits for the `g` and `G` conversions, or the maximum number of bytes to be written for s conversions. **The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an
  >   asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional decimal integer;** if only the period is
  >   specified, the precision is taken as zero. If a precision appears with any other
  >   conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.
- `printf("Test:%+0*d", 10, 20);`

  where, the `0` is used as a ***flag***. As per the syntax, *all* the flags should appear together, before any other conversion specification entry, you cannot just put it *anywhere* in the conversion specification and expect the compiler to follow your *intention*.

  Again, to quote, (*and my emphasis*)

  > Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. After the `%`, **the following
  >   appear in sequence:**
  >
  > - Zero or more *flags* (in any order) [...]
  > - An optional minimum *field width* [...]
  > - An optional *precision* [...]
  > - An optional *length modifier* [...]
  > - A *conversion specifier* [....]

Comment: Great. I would suggest an *explicit* mention of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because many newbies don't grasp that notion.

Comment: Hmm, no, he's not supplying nonsense to the compiler and it is not free to do something arbitrary.  The printf() function implementation can however do whatever it wants with that string.

Comment: @HansPassant: you are sort-of right. But a conforming compiler can (and often does, e.g. at least [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) handle `printf` specifically.

Comment: @HansPassant From the point of the standard, it's UB. Individual implementations may have fixed behaviour for each scenario, but the standard does not mention anything specificc , at all, not even implementation defined behaviour. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant From the point of the standard, it's UB. Individual implementations may have fixed behaviour for each scenario, but the standard does not mention anything specfic , at all, not even implementation defined nehaviour. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Can anybody mention the reson behind the downvote? What did I miss or misunderstood?

Comment: @chqrlie Sir, the problem with that is, the _intention_ maybe valid but the syntax is wrong. That is what I tried to point out, but I see your point, too. Let me edit to clarify that. thanks. :)

Comment: @chqrlie any better now?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: yes, much better, btw I am not the downvoter. Yet I wonder what the output should be for `%+.0d` for the value `0`.  A single `+` character I suppose.

Comment: @chqrlie well, isn;t it _minimum_?

Comment: @chqrlie I know sir you're not the downvoter, then before me asking i would have received a constructive comment, I know that much. :) These are mostly pass-by downvotes, none of the ones who actually bothered to leave comment and engage into positive discussion. Asked just to be sure that I wasn't missing something obvious, but never matters much, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

In complement of [Sourav Ghosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575199/841108); an important notion is that of [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is tricky. Be sure to read Lattner's blog: [*What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

So, leaving on purpose (or perhaps depending upon) some undefined behavior in your code is intentional malpractice. Don't do that. In the very rare cases you want to do that (I cannot see any), please document it and justify yourself in some comment.

Be aware that if indeed `printf` is implemented by the C standard library, it can be (and often *is*) specially handled by the compiler (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and GNU libc, that magic might happens using internally `__builtin_printf`)

The C99 & C11 standards are *partially* specifying the behavior of `printf` but does leave some undefined behavior cases to ease the implementation. You are unlikely to full understand or be able to mimic these cases. And the implementation itself could change (for example, on my Debian Linux, an upgrade of `libc` might change the *undefined behavior* of `printf`)

If you want to understand more `printf` study the source of some C standard library *implementation* (e.g. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), whose code is quite readable) and of the GCC implementation (assuming a Linux operating system).

But maintainers of GNU libc and of GCC (& even of the Linux kernel, thru syscalls) stay free to change the *undefined* behavior (of `printf` and anything else)

In practice, always compile with  `gcc -Wall` (and probably also `-g`) if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Don't accept any warnings (so improve your own code till you get none).

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf` format is incorrect: the flags must precede the width specifier.

After it handles `*` as the width specifier, `printf` expects either a `.` or a length modifier or a conversion specifier, `0` being none of these, the behavior is undefined.

Your library's implementation of `printf` does something bizarre, it seems to handle `*` by replacing it with the actual width argument... A side effect of the implementation.  Others may do something else, including aborting the program. Such a format error would be especially risky if followed by a `%s` conversion.

Changing your code to `printf("Test:%+0*d", 10, 20);` should produce the expected output:

```
Test:+000000020
```